# TYPO3 indexed_search rename placeholder

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I tried to rename indexed_search placeholder label in TYPO3 9.5.5.

The template looks like this:

```
<f:form.textfield name="search[sword]" value="{sword}" id="tx-indexedsearch-searchbox-sword" class="tx-indexedsearch-searchbox-sword form-control mr-sm-2 form-control-sm" placeholder="{f:translate(key: 'LLL:EXT:indexed_search/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml:form.submit')}" />
```

How can I change the value of the placeholder?

I tried this :

```
plugin.tx_indexed_search._LOCAL_LANG.default.form.submit = New Placeholder Text
```

and this :

```
plugin.tx_indexed_search.locallang.default.form.submit = New Placeholder Text
```

But both did not work.

Thanks,
rimmeh

Answer (score 1):

If you use your custom extension for your FLUID templating then please use `<f:translate key='form.submit' extensionName='your_extension_key'/>`
and create all lacallang files in your extension

You can find below code

```
<f:form.textfield  name="search[sword]" value="{sword}" id="tx-indexedsearch-searchbox-sword" class="tx-indexedsearch-searchbox-sword form-control" placeholder="{f:translate(key: 'form.submit', extensionName: 'your_extension_key')}"/>
```

If you are using fileadmin base then you have to create a typoscript object like below

```
lib.langFile=TEXT
lib.langFile.value=LLL:EXT:indexed_search/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xm
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
lib.langFile.value=LLL:EXT:indexed_search/Resources/Private/Language/de.locallang.xml
[end]
```

Your code will be

```
<f:form.textfield name="search[sword]" value="{sword}" id="tx-indexedsearch-searchbox-sword" class="tx-indexedsearch-searchbox-sword form-control mr-sm-2 form-control-sm" placeholder="<f:translate key='{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: \'lib.langFile\')}:form.submit'/>" />
```

I know this is strange but it's a good solution!!

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i dont want to use a custom extension is just want to rename the placeholder. I cant believe this simple and completly common task is such a problem in typo3 :D

Comment: which template method have you used?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
plugin.tx_indexedsearch._LOCAL_LANG.default.form.submit = New placeholder text
```

And this for German :

```
plugin.tx_indexedsearch._LOCAL_LANG.de.form.submit = New placeholder text
```

Comment: thanks for the relpy, but this doesnt work. In Typo3 9 the indexed Search 9.5.5. is renamed with underscore "tx_indexed_search" is correct.